# Javascript: Input type radio

Tags: javascript

How can I select input type radio by just clicking the space around it?

[image]

Comment: You would need to add an eventhandler to the "space around it" ...

Comment: Can you tell me how? thanks

Comment: not without further details from your side ...

Comment: This could also be achieved with a label styled display block wrapping the input.

Comment: I added 1 comment down bellow you can check this for more details

Comment: @pellay it worked thanck you <3 <3

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) tag:

```html
<input type="radio" name="box" id="box">
<label for="box">Your content here</label>
```

Clicking on the label toggles the input.

Comment: Yes it would work but I dont want to have label text.

Comment: @Georgesnjder You can just fill the label with `&nbsp` to fill it with a space.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element. There are two ways to use it with a radio button, as shown below.

```html
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="options">
    <span>Option 1 - Inside Label</span>
  </label>

  <br>

  <input type="radio" name="options" id="button2">
  <label for="button2">
    <span>Option 2 - Outside Label</span>
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Just looking at your picture, it looks like you want a checkbox rather than a radio button. Radio buttons are used for their exclusiveness; clicking one will disable the others (they should have a name attribute). Labels can also be used the same with checkboxes, and can be expanded to fit the required region using CSS.